# Compare array in Powershell

Tags: powershell

Question, I'd like to be able to compare a list of objects against an array of strings.  More or less, like using the Sql 'IN' operator (where TableName IN('Table1','Table2','Table3').

Specifically, I'm using the SMO table list, and I'd like to return only the tables by name that are contained within an array of table names.

For example:
$tablelist = @("Address","Phone", "Email")

sl "SQLSERVER:SQL\SERVERNAME\DEFAULT\DATABASES\DATABASEName\TABLES"

$tables = gci | where{$_.Name -->  wtf do I do here with the $tablelist, if this is possible?}

TIA!
B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

Seems like `-in` is added in v3.0. Assumed that it was there all along!

So in v2.0, you have to use `-contains` or `-eq`:

```
$tables = gci | where { $tablelist -contains  $_.Name}
```

or

```
$tables = gci | where { $tablelist -eq $_.Name}
```

---

There are multiple operators that you can use:

```
$a = 1,2,3

1 -in $a  #True
4 -in $a  #False

$a -contains 1  #True
$a -contains 4  #True

$a -eq 1  #gives 1
$a -eq 4  #returns nothing
```

The `-in` operator is similar to what you are used to in SQL. When used with array, `-eq` sees if the element is present in the array and returns the element if so. So you can use it like `if($a -eq 1)`

So in your case, you can do something like:

```
$tables = gci | where {$_.Name -in $tablelist }
```

Comment: is available in posh 2.0 the comparison operator -in?? why I can find it?

Comment: @Christian - I just realized it is there only in v3.0!! I thought it was there all along. Sorry about that.

Comment: Close, but not quite.  The $tablelist is an array as well.  I love the -in functionality, seems exactly what I was looking for, but I suspect what I am trying to do (compare an array with an array and only return objects with the same name) will probably have to be done using a custom filter.  I was just curious as to whether or not this functionality already existed, but I was just not seeing it.  This is functionality I've needed on many occasions.  Thanks for the suggestions/help guys!  -B-

Comment: @Bender - What you are asking here and what you say in the question do not match up. Compare array with array is not in your question. When you are piping and using where object, where does the need for array to array comparison come in?

Comment: I apologize, I just realized now that my code example that I provided was indeed incorrect.  Essentially, I want to take the tables collection and filter it by the array of table names in the $tablenames array.  Sorry for the confusion.  I doubt this is possible without using the -in.  Well, it's possible probably using the %{} operator, but I was curious as to whether or not there was an already existing way to do this with a filter.  Once again, sorry for misleading you guys.

Answer (score 0):

```
$tables = gci | where{$tablist -contains $_.name}
```

The `-contains` comparison operator is your best choice for this I think.

Answer (score 0):

Scott,
It sounds like the way you want to go about this is by using -Contains.

Here's a quick example using [SQLPSX](http://sqlpsx.codeplex.com/)

```
Import-Module SQLServer;
$TableList= 'AWBuildVersion', 'bigProduct', 'bigTransactionHistory', 'DatabaseLog'
Get-SqlDatabase -sqlserver localhost\R2 -dbname AdventureWorks |
Get-SqlTable |
where {$TableList -contains $_.name}|
select name, DataSpaceUsed
```